# How to add new div after 4 result in ngFor angular 5 when we clicked

Tags: jquery, angular, angular5

I want to show data in new div under every row. For instance, suppose we have 3 rows total and every row has 4 images i.e in one row four images are there. And suppose I click on the third image from the first row. Then new div should open under the first row. A similar feature like Google image section.

```
I tried below code:

<div *ngFor="let searchMediadata of searchMediaResult; let i = index" class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<div class="result-thumb-outer">
    <div (click)="openImageDiv()" class="image-holder">
        <img src="{{searchMediadata.file_url}}" alt="">
        <div class="image-thumb-content">
          <div class="image-title">
           {{searchMediadata.title}}
          </div>
          <div class="image-date">{{searchMediadata.date | date: 'MMMM, y'}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="is-clearfix" *ngIf="(index + 1) % 4 == 0">This is testing please ignore it</div>
```

I want to like this:

https://www.google.com/search?q=add+new+div+after+4+result+in+in+ngFor+angular+2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN9_K9tPraAhUOUI8KHd9uBpcQ_AUIDCgD&biw=1301&bih=678

And when we click on any image new div open for show more data of that particular image.

Thanks,
Rohit

Comment: I removed the Java tag since your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with Java.

Answer (score 1):

Divide each row into two divs, top-div and bottom-div(display None)
First div should hold four divs and each div should accomodate an image.
Click on any image should display(show) the bottom-div with the desired content.

Comment: Thanks, @Padmapriya, do have any sample code. Actually, I didn't what you trying to say.

Comment: <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div *ngFor="let searchMediadata of searchMediaResult; let i = index">
   <div (click)="openImageDiv()" class="image-holder">
    <img src="{{searchMediadata.file_url}}" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-thumb-content">
     <div class="image-title">
      {{searchMediadata.title}}
     </div>
     <div class="image-date">{{searchMediadata.date | date: 'MMMM, y'}}</div>
  </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table> Your openImageDiv() should be able to show or hide the bottom div.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pipe for that
this will help you

it will show only 5 data and if you click on next it will show you another 5data

write code in HTML file

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of paymentHistData | paginate: { itemsPerPage:15, currentPage: payment,id:'paymentReport'} ">
</tr>

 <div style="margin-left: -49px;font-size: 15px">
                                <pagination-controls (pageChange)="payment =$event;" id="paymentReport"></pagination-controls>
                            </div>
```

and write this in angular .ts file

import this

```
import {Component, OnInit, Pipe, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'paginate',
    pure: false
})
```

if any query plase write on comment

Comment: HAVE YOU TRIED IT. ITHINK THIS CODE IS FOR AJ-4?

Comment: @chandrakant You can use this code in angular  4 and upper version